# Android Layout, displaying Multiple Columns

Tags: android

I want to display text such that it would be like:

1. TITLE 1.1

text about title 1.1

2. TITLE 1.2

text about title 1.2

1. TITLE 2.1

text about title 2.1

> > and so on

it would be a scrolling windows, but another problem is text could be lengthy and could span multiple lines. What do you recommend i should breakup my layout with. The length will be more then the screen height so I need scrollbars. Plus need to keep title bold.

Basically I would be printing this text from a String Array. Is it possible to display it directly from arrays or i can also work with simple strings but need to know how should i breakup my layout. like scrollview -> table layout or what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use String Array. I'd recommed to look at `ListActivity` and `ArrayAdapter`. Here is the [info](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) to start from.